# Script to share all private Pinterest Pins (except for a few specified ones) with a given set of users

Tags: pinterest

I really don't like the idea of public Pins on Pinterest, and almost of all of my Pins are secret.

So now I would like a script, either command-line or web-interface, e.g. one written in PHP, which will interface to the Pinterest API to invite a set of specified users (whose e-mails I would have to list) to access all of my secret boards (except for the ones I specify).

Is there an easy way to do this, e.g. via a Pinterest API, and does a script to do what I'm looking for exist (perhaps on GitHub)?